# creating a function that takes a list of Ints and returns the list with any odd numbers squared

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function very similar to filter using the odd function that takes a list and returns that list with any odd numbers squared.

ex

```
gchi> sqrodd [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,9,4,25]
```

what I have and believe is close is

```
sqrodd :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
sqrodd odd []     = []
sqrodd odd (x:xs) = if odd x
                    then (x*x) :sqrodd odd xs
                    else x : sqrodd odd xs
```

but I get errors with the function definition saying "couldn't match expected type `a -> Bool` with actual type `[a]`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you wrote yourself, you want a function that takes a list as argument and returns another list, so instead of having type signature

```
    sqrodd :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

You should make a function with a type signature that looks like this

```
    sqrodd :: [a] -> [a]
```

which is exactly what you have written on the beginning.
Because of that compiler expects, that the first argument of this function will be a function of (a -> bool). 
You should remove odd from arguments list and change type signature as shown above. This will cause the function to use odd from prelude instead of expecting filter function as argument.

Another way of doing it, is renaming you function as, for example sqrfiltered and then you can define sqrodd as partially applied sqrfiltered

```
    sqrodd = sqrfiltered odd
```

Not tested, but it should be right.

Answer (score 7):

Your `sqrodd` function has **two** parameters: the first is an oddness-predicate `a -> Bool` and the second is a list of elements `[a]`. In your example usage, you pass `[1..5]` as the **first** argument, in place of the `a -> Bool` predicate.

However, what you really want is to **not** have two parameters, i.e. change `sqrodd` to a single-parameter function `sqrodd :: [a] -> [a]` and just use [the function `odd` from the Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:odd).

Note that you'll still need to be a bit more restrictive in your `sqrodd` type because it is not true that you can apply `odd` or `(*)` on elements of any type `a`; you may want to read up on typeclasses once you get there to get over that next hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

The filter function examines each element in a list and returns a new list that only contains the elements satisfying the condition.

But what you want to accomplish is to transform a list to a new list; the new list has the same number of elements of the old one. You're not filtering out anything; you're mapping elements from one list to another according to some rules.

Here are two possible ways to write your function.

```
oddSquared, oddSquared' :: [Int] -> [Int]

oddSquared l = [ if (x `mod` 2 /= 0) then x^2 else x | x <- l ]

oddSquared'  = map (\x -> if odd x then x^2 else x)
```